# Spark access Row object value

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase

I want to iterate a dataframe by partitions and for each partition iterate all of its rows and create a deleteList of them that will contain HBase's delete objects for each row.
I'm using Spark and HBase with Java and I've created a Row object with the following code:

```
df.foreachPartition((ForeachPartitionFunction<Row> iterator -> {
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = RowFactory.create(iterator.next());
    deleteList.add(new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(row))));
  }
}
```

But it won't work because I cannot access row's value correctly. While df has one column named "hbase_key".

Comment: Please show more of your code. What is `iterator`? What key used for hbase table?

Comment: Yes. Look at what I've edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your post which class exactly is `Row`, but I suspect it is `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` ?

If that's the case, try the methods like `getString(i)` or similar, where i is the index of the column in the row you are trying to access.

Again, depending on how you are configuring your Hbase access, I suspect that in your case the 0 index would be the value of the row-key of the physical HBase table, and the subsequent indices will be the respective column values that are returned with your row. But again, that would depend on how exactly you arrived at this point in your code.

Your `Row` object should have methods to access other data types as well, such as `getInt(i)`, etc.

Comment: Yes that's indeed `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`. That was helpful. Thanks